# Error al abrir archivo en otra ventana

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-objeto

Estoy intentando abrir un documento y cargarlo en una ventana nueva; el documento esta en formato JSON.

Esta es la función que utilizo para crear una clave que posterior me sirve para el path donde se encuentra el documento que voy a leer y luego cargarlo.

```
function pasarClave(e) {
  if(!e) e = window.event;
  let a = e.target.textContent;
  let cl = a.replaceAll(" ","_");
  let clave = "../"+cl+"/info.json";
  localStorage.setItem("clave", clave);
  window.open(URL,"_blank");
}
```

Esto sucede en un h3 al que mediante javascript le agrego un `addEventListener("click",pasarClave)` y en otro javascript tengo:

```
window.onload = cargarDatosP();

function cargarDatosP() {
    let path = sessionStorage.getItem("clave");
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET',path,true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        var i, resI, j, resJ = "";
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var datos = JSON.parse(this.response);
.
.
.
```

**¿Alguien sabe si estoy correcto en la línea del `xhttp.open()` a lo que le paso el path ya que aunque lo pruebe en un servidor externo no puedo acceder en consola a la variable datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré es creando la `clave = "CARPETA_RAIZ/"+cl+"/info.js"`, además en la instrucción para abrir la ventana le puse de argumento: `URL,"_self"` y en la función cargarDatosP() especificar que la clave se obtiene del `localStorage`.

En sí más yo tenía más problemas internamente en la organización de mis documentos lo que conllevaba a tener este error.